# Creating faceted plots to show how X varies with 2 variables

Tags: r, ggplot2, rstudio, facet

this is a pretty basic question, but I'm a pretty basic script writer when it comes to RStudio, so if I could get an outline for the code to use, it would be fantastic. There are of course resources that give a general idea for faceted plots, or such plots in other applications but I'm having trouble translating this to mine in particular.

What I'm trying to do is draw a plot that shows how X (in this case distance flown by a paper plane) is affected by 2 variables (in this case height from which the plane is thrown, and the weight of the plane as measured by a number of paperclips).

The data I have is a csv (named planes2), in which is displayed columns for Distance, Paperclips (amount) and Height for each "pilot".

I appreciate any inputs! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Here's my implementation:

```
library(ggplot2);                   # Adds the ggplot2 library

# Sample data
pilots <- data.frame(
    w = c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3),
    h = c(10,10,10,15,15,15,20,20,20),
    X = c(3,2.8,2.6,6,5.8,5.6,9,8.8,8.6));

pilots.plot <- ggplot(pilots) +     # Plot object associated with data frame
    geom_point(aes(h, X)) +         # Points with position based on height and distance
    facet_wrap(~ w);                # Facets for each level of weight
```

Since you'll be loading the data from a .csv file instead, you'll probably want to replace the second line with something like:

```
pilots <- read.csv("planes2.csv", header = TRUE);
```

Check out the [options for `facet_wrap()`](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/facet_wrap.html) to see some other ways you can push the facets around. You could also include `color = w` in your aes() call to represent the data without the use of facets.

*Edit:* Substitute your csv's header names for h, w and X in my code.

*Edit:* As David pointed out, you need to call the plotting object, `pilots.plot`, to have R display it.

Comment: You may want to actually display the plot by adding `pilots.plot` at the end of your code. You can also probably add something like `+ stat_smooth(aes(h, X), method = "lm")` there